# How do I get local time in Perl with UTC Offset?

Tags: perl, timezone

I know how to get local time using timezone conversion if I have the location:

```
my $localTime = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'America/New_York' );
```

But I currently only have UTC TimeZone number, for example:

```
my $UTCzone = 5;
my $UTCzone = -2;
etc.
```

How do I convert in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
DateTime->now( time_zone => '+0500' );
```

`perldoc DateTime` says

> The time_zone parameter can be either a scalar or a DateTime::TimeZone object. A string will simply be passed to the DateTime::TimeZone->new method as its "name" parameter. This string may be an Olson DB time zone name ("America/Chicago"), an offset string ("+0630"),

Answer (score 2):

DateTime accepts offsets for time zones. For example, New York is currently at `UTC-0400`, so you can use

```
DateTime->now( time_zone => '-0400' );  # Or -0330, +0100, etc
```

But note that this isn't the same as providing a time zone of `America/New_York` since New York's offsets changes twice a year for DST.

```
$ perl -MDateTime -E'
   for my $time_zone (qw(America/New_York -0400)) {
      my $dt = DateTime->now( time_zone => $time_zone );

      say "Timezone       = $time_zone";
      say "Now            = ", $dt->strftime("%T");
      say "UTC            = ", $dt->clone->set_time_zone("UTC")->strftime("%T");
      $dt->add( months => 6 );
      say "+6 months      = ", $dt->strftime("%T");
      say "+6 months, UTC = ", $dt->clone->set_time_zone("UTC")->strftime("%T");
      say "";
   }
'
Timezone       = America/New_York
Now            = 19:36:33
UTC            = 23:36:33
+6 months      = 19:36:33
+6 months, UTC = 00:36:33

Timezone       = -0400
Now            = 19:36:33
UTC            = 23:36:33
+6 months      = 19:36:33
+6 months, UTC = 23:36:33
```